# Why test not fail when swipeRight on RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, ui-testing

Here my xml with RecyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/tradersRecyclerView"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:visibility="@{handler.tradersList.size > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tradersToolBar"        
   tools:listitem="@layout/trader_list_item" />
```

When **swiping lef**t on list's item than I show sub items **(Resume, Stop)**

Something like this:

[image]

The sub-items show **only when swipe left**. When swipe right **nothing happens**.

Here Espresso's test that check that **swipeLeft** is work

```
 @Test
 fun scroll_itemList_swipeLeft() {
    // scroll
    onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount));
    // swipe
    onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount, swipeLeft()))
 }
```

Nice. The test passes.

Now I create a test that must fail when swipe right. Because when swipe right **nothing happens**

```
@Test
fun scroll_itemList_notSwipeRight() {
     // scroll
     onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount));
     // swipe
     onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
                .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount, ViewActions.swipeRight()))
 }
```

but this test also success pass. Why?
I need create test that check than swipe right **nothing happens**

P.S.
Here work tests when swipe left and swipe right

```
@Test
fun itemList_swipeLeft_isDisplayedSwipeContainer() {
    onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount));
    onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount, swipeLeft()))
    onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.tradersRecyclerView).atPositionOnView(checkItemCount, R.id.swipeContainer))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}

@Test
fun itemList_swipeRight_notDisplayedSwipeContainer() {
    onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
            .perform(scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount));
    onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
            .perform(actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount, ViewActions.swipeRight()))
    onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.tradersRecyclerView).atPositionOnView(checkItemCount, R.id.swipeContainer))
            .check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))
}
```

Comment: On the test, you're not checking anything. You're just performing actions. That's why both of them are successful

Comment: @LucaNicoletti If I can't swipe right why Espresso not throw any exception?

Comment: Why can't you swipe right?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti because when I try swipe right nothing happens. Not show sub items (Resume, Stop)

Comment: Does your app crash when you swipe right? No? So test won't fail. Nothing will happen during the test, but you're not stating (in the tests) that something should happen.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Do you mean that test success criteria is show sub items or not? If swipe and sub items show that test pass. But if I swipe and sub items not show - test fail. Is it correct?

Comment: No, from you're code you're not checking for items after performing swipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this to your testes (both of them):

```
onView(withId(R.id.*your_resume_button_id*)).check(mathes(isDisplayed()))
```

This will add a check on visibility for a `view` that should **only** be visible when swiping to left.

So the first test will pass and the second will fail as this view won't be visible when swiping to right.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, your solution help me. Thanks